# Sum list of values within a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I'm sure this could be somewhere in `SO` but I can't seem to find it. I am trying to `sum` values expressed within `lists` from a `pandas` `df`. Example

I can achieve this using this following from an `array`:

```
array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

array = [sum(a) for a in zip(*array)]
```

But when the values are housed within a `df` I can't get it working. Here is my attempt:

```
d = ({
    'Val' : [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],   
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df = [sum(a) for a in zip(df['Val'])]

print(df)

df = [sum(a) for a in zip(df['Val'])]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: You can use lambda to apply sum on each list, df['Val'].apply(lambda x: sum(x))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `*` star operator to unpack:

```
df = [sum(a) for a in zip(*df['Val'])]

print(df)
[12, 15, 18]
```

Now it passes lists, thats why you get this error:

```
for a in zip(df['Val']):
    print(a)

print('\n')

for a in zip(*df['Val']):  # <--- notice the *
    print(a)

# Output

([1, 2, 3],)
([4, 5, 6],)
([7, 8, 9],)


(1, 4, 7)
(2, 5, 8)
(3, 6, 9)
```

Comment: The first list is [1, 2, 3]. The sum is 6.  The method above returns 12 as the first sum , which is incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is to send this to a list in the list comprension do the following:

```
d = ({
'Val' : [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],   
 })
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df = [sum(a) for a in df['Val'].tolist()]
```

Doing list comprehensions with a data frame is really slow.

Comment: The first list is [1, 2, 3]. The sum is 6. The method above also returns 6 as the first sum, which seems correct to me, unlike the other methods in this post?